# SharedPreferences deleted after DataStore migration

Tags: android, android-jetpack-datastore

I ran into this and the fix is simple but non-obvious, so I figured I would share.

I was migrating a single field from `SharedPreferences` to a `Preferences DataStore` and using the default `SharedPreferencesMigration` to do so. Every time the migration would run, my `SharedPreferences` file was deleted.

Answer (score 4):

If you are migrating a single `SharedPreferences` preference to a `Preferences DataStore` (or multiple prefs but not all of them), you *must* provide a set of keys to the `SharedPreferencesMigration`. Not doing so will result in your `SharedPreferences` file being deleted.

This is the `SharedPreferencesMigration`'s `cleanUp()` function that runs after the migration:

```
override suspend fun cleanUp() {
    val sharedPrefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit()

    if (keySet == null) {
        sharedPrefsEditor.clear()
    } else {
        keySet.forEach { key ->
            sharedPrefsEditor.remove(key)
        }
    }

    if (!sharedPrefsEditor.commit()) {
        throw IOException("Unable to delete migrated keys from SharedPreferences.")
    }

    if (sharedPrefs.all.isEmpty() && context != null && name != null) {
        deleteSharedPreferences(context, name)
    }

    keySet?.clear()
}
```

Notice that the migration will remove every key that was migrated, or if no keys were provided, call `clear()` on the Editor, which removes all keys. Then if all keys are removed it will delete the file.

The fix for this is simply to provide a set of keys to the `SharedPreferencesMigration`, which it provides as an optional parameter.

```
SharedPreferencesMigration(
    context = context,
    sharedPreferencesName = "preferences file name"
    keysToMigrate = setOf("your key name")
)
```

Comment: With DataStore v.1.0.0 this is stated pretty clearly in the docs: If the SharedPreferences is empty once the migration completes, this migration will attempt to delete it. ....  If keysToMigrate is not set, all keys will be migrated from the existing SharedPreferences.